# How to add Items to GridView in C# Windows Store App (Win8)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datatemplate, windows-store-apps

To keep things simple let's just say I have a c# Windows Store Project for Windows 8 that has the following items:

- GridView (PlatformsGrid)
- List«PlatformSearchResult» (allPlatforms)
- DataTemplate (PlatformDataTemplate) in standardstyles.xaml

allPlatforms is a collection of "PlatformSearchResult"objects populated from an online API, and has the following 3 properties:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Alias

I am able to add a new item to the gridview for each object that exists in my allPlatforms collection, however the items are blank and do not show the data from my objects.

A quick summary of the current code looks like this:

**XAML Markup:**

```
<!-- Platforms Content -->
<GridView x:Name="PlatformsGrid" Grid.Row="1"
  CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlatformDataTemplate}" >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" 
              VerticalChildrenAlignment="Top" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

**Data Template**

```
<!-- Platform Item Template -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="PlatformDataTemplate">
    <Grid Background="#FF939598" Height="250" Width="250">
        <Image Source="/SampleImage.png"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#CC000000" 
                Height="90" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="242" Height="62" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alias}" 
                   Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="186" Height="14" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9" Opacity="0.49"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Controlling Function**

```
    private async void FetchItemInfo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get List of Top Games
        List<PlatformSearchResult> allPlatforms = new List<PlatformSearchResult>();
        allPlatforms = await GamesDB.GetPlatforms();

        // Dynamically Create Platform Tiles
        foreach (PlatformSearchResult platform in allPlatforms)
        {
            PlatformsGrid.DataContext = platform;
            PlatformsGrid.Items.Add(platform);
        }
    }
```

How do I get the added items to show the appropriate object properties (ignoring the image for now), I'm just interested in populating the content of the TextBlocks.

I appreciate any help anyone can provide!

Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the allplatforms list through a property to the gridview as the itemssource. This assumes, of course, that the datacontext for the gridview or the page is the class that contains your allplatforms property. If not, you'll have to do that too.

Set the datacontext either through code behind

this.grid.DataContext = class()//

or through binding

```
<!-- Platforms Content -->
<GridView x:Name="PlatformsGrid" Grid.Row="1"
  CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
  ItemsSource = "{Binding AllPlatforms}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlatformDataTemplate}" >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" 
              VerticalChildrenAlignment="Top" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

You can check the Windows 8 app samples provided on msdn.

EDIT: Your platform object must have the properties for name and alias that you have added as Binding.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do in you controlling function is

```
private async void FetchItemInfo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get List of Top Games
    List<PlatformSearchResult> allPlatforms = new List<PlatformSearchResult>();
    allPlatforms = await GamesDB.GetPlatforms();

    PlatformsGrid.ItemsSource = allPlatforms;    
}
```